# Unable to create RegisteredServer in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to register a new database to `Registered Server` in `SQL Server Management Studio` via `C# code` because I create a database dynamically and I want to see them in `Registered Servers`:

[image: Registered Server]

I found out it is possible with `'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers'`. But I could not find any sample to work with it. I tried to use Powershell sample to implement it:
[Professional PowerShell-based SQL Server SMO Recipes](https://blog.netnerds.net/smo-recipes/)

 but I got this error when I try to create the registered server:

> 'registeredServer.Create()' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcMissingParentException'
>
> "Must set the Parent to perform this operation."

```
var registeredServer = new RegisteredServer(serverGroup, "/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/ServerGroup/AzureDatabases/RegisteredServer/Azure-Tests");
registeredServer.ConnectionString = @"....";
registeredServer.Create();
```

Comment: Are you looking to create the server or the database, as your question seems confusing..  if  you wish to connect to an existing server and create a database that should be doabe.

Comment: Maybe this will help. It does not answer your question directly but does contain a little code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433435/cant-enumerate-sql-server-2008-registered-servers-with-Smo

Comment: This is a PowerShell equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602992/creating-registered-servers-via-powershell-in-ssms

Comment: @Alex: I want it in c#

Comment: Your constructor parameters don't seem right. I suggest you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.registeredservers.registeredserver.-ctor?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Smo_RegisteredServers_RegisteredServer__ctor_Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Smo_RegisteredServers_ServerGroup_System_String_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `SQL Server 2017` and `2018`. When I use this code:

```
    private void ConnectToCentralManagementServer()
    {
        var serverConnection = new ServerConnection
        {                
            LoginSecure = false,
            ServerInstance = "localhost",
            Login = "UserName",
            Password = "Password",
            DatabaseName = "Database",                
        };

        var registeredServersStore = new RegisteredServersStore(serverConnection);
        var databaseEngineServerGroup = registeredServersStore.ServerGroups["DatabaseEngineServerGroup"];
        var serverName = "TestServer";
        var registeredServer = new RegisteredServer(serverName)
        {
            Parent = databaseEngineServerGroup,
            ConnectionString = testConnectionString,
            Description = "This is a sample connection to Test server",
            ServerName = "TestServer",                
        };
        if (databaseEngineServerGroup.RegisteredServers.Count(c => c.Name == serverName) == 0)
        {
            registeredServer.Create();
        }
    }
```

It is visible in `SQL Server 2017` in `Central management Servers` section.

[image]

I could not specify the database and it is a default database:
[image]

on the other hand, I could not register Azure Database. I found out it should be registered as `Local Servers Group`

When I use this code:

```
    private void ConnectToLocalServerGroup()
    {
        var databaseEngineServerGroup = RegisteredServersStore.LocalFileStore.ServerGroups["DatabaseEngineServerGroup"];

        var serverName = "Database on Sever";
        var registeredServer = new RegisteredServer(serverName)
        {
            Parent = databaseEngineServerGroup,
            ConnectionString = localConnectionString,
            Description = "This is a sample connection to Test server",
            ServerName = "Server",
        };

        if (databaseEngineServerGroup.RegisteredServers.Count(c => c.Name == serverName) == 0)
        {
            registeredServer.Create();
        }
    }
```

It is visible in `SQL Server 2018` in `Local Server Groups` section.