# How to specify Authentication in RegisteredServer

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database

based on my question about creating RegisteredServer in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers,
[Unable to create RegisteredServer in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642945/unable-to-create-registeredserver-in-microsoft-sqlserver-management-registeredse), I work on adding a database from Azure SQL Server. I could add a database but the authentication is based on `Windows Authentication`
[image]

Absolutely, I can not connect to Azure:
[image]

Therefore I am looking for a solution to specify authentication in `C# code`. It is strange because I pass my connection string with username and password:

```
        var registeredServer = new RegisteredServer(serverName)
        {

            ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=...;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=...;Password=....;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved it, we need to install `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` package in order to set the connection string:

```
 Install-Package System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData -Version 4.6.0
```

then, we need to specify CredentialPersistenceType  and AuthenticationType  like this:

```
        var registeredServer = new RegisteredServer(databaseEngineServerGroup, serverName)
        {
            ConnectionString = localConnectionString,
            Description = $"This is a sample connection to {serverName}",
            CredentialPersistenceType = CredentialPersistenceType.PersistLoginNameAndPassword,
            AuthenticationType = 1,
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Azure SQL [supports AAD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#connecting-using-azure-ad-identities). As far as I know, the windows authentication is suitable for local SQL Server.

[image]

And, you need to [set AAD admin for your Azure SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication)

[image]

After that, you can conect to your Azure SQL with AAD credential. If your local accounts are synced to Azure AD with AD Connect. Then you should be able to use AD credential to connect to Azure SQL too.