# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers, Version=15.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

Based on my answer in [Unable to create RegisteredServer in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642945/unable-to-create-registeredserver-in-microsoft-sqlserver-management-registeredse?noredirect=1#comment103683800_58642945), I installed

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData
```

It worked on Consol Application based on .Net Core 2.0 and ClassLibrary based on .Net Standard 2.0:

[image]
[image]

Now I use them in my main C# Solution with Web Application based on .Net Framework 4.7.1 and Class Library based on .Net Standard 2.0:

[image]
[image]

I got this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers, Version=15.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

This is the detail:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers, Version=15.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Code/Platform/Platform.Web/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Code\Platform\Platform.Web\bin
Calling assembly : Application.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Code\Platform\Platform.Web\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers, Version=15.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cd41b801/927eac2d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cd41b801/927eac2d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Code/Platform/Platform.Web/bin/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I tried different solution like 
[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference) but they did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, a combination of solutions worked:

1) Delete the `obj` and `bin` folders

2) Update the  references from web.config file, and then run this command from the NuGet Package Manager console in order to add new bindings:

```
Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect
```

3) Deleting `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\~\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ directory`

4) Adding `dependentAssembly` to web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.100.0.0" newVersion="15.100.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

It should be the same as project.cspj:

```
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers, Version=15.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects.150.18208.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```